# When should I choose a PDW as a primary weapon?

Tags: battlefield-3

When playing Battlefield 3, I use the PP-2000 as a primary weapon for all kits but support where I tend to chose a heavy machine gun. Even though I tend to use it at mid-to-close range I still have issues with the enemy killing me with non-PDW weapons. I'm at rank 25 so I would say I'm a confident player and have got a number of weapon unlocks for different kits, although it's difficult to chose between them all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**PDW**

Though outclassed in most areas by other weapons, PDWs have the **lowest hipfire spread** (only rivaled by bullpup carbines equipped with laser sight), generally **reload faster** than other weapons, and **allow the player to move at full speed** (unless aiming down sight with mid-range scopes).

The majority of the PDW's (UMP-45, PDW-R and AS Val being exceptions) **damage dropoff doesn't start until 12 meters** in comparison to the usual 8 meters by most assault rifles and carbines, meaning that the PP-2000 and the M5K for instance will **only need 4 shots to a torso to kill at 12 meters** where a typical assault rifle would need 5.

**Shoud be super effective in close range**

Comment: Surely in close-range I'd be better to use a shotgun?

Comment: In close-range combat, they are less effective than a shotgun, but they are more accurate and have better range than shotguns making them more versatile.

Comment: Besides that you are more efficient on midrange, because there is nearly no map - not even metro - where a shotgun is the best choice. Although keep in mind that PDWs can equip Lasersights and Supressors at the same time. Not much normal primary weapons allow this combination :)

Comment: also shotguns (pump actions) are usually hit or miss. Either you one shot the guy or you die before you are done pumping. Semi Auto shotguns do less damage per shots so a PDW has a chance versus them.

Comment: 4 vs 5 shots in normal mode. In hardcore full health is 60, so it's 3 shots for both (for 75 vs 73 damage).

Answer (score 4):

PDWs are a great weapon from short-mid to medium range encounters. Great accuracy in the first couple of shots and an amazing rate of fire make these weapons pretty much unbeatable for fighting in close quarters or medium size city streets.

I personally like to use one due to the amount of speed you can maintain whilst firing, they also seem to ready faster than most weapons and fire accurately from the hip even after sprinting, making these weapons a great tool for rushing and game modes such as CTF or RUSH.